# Retrieving a subset of a binary search tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For a binary tree object I'm implementing with the private fields

```
X key;
Y value;
Tree<X,Y> left;
Tree<X,Y> right;
```

I have a method `public Tree<X,Y> subset(X startKey, X endKey)` that needs to return a Tree including all of the keys in between the node with `startKey` and the node with `endKey`, and their corresponding values. This method also needs to be performed using recursion.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to get a tree (which would probably look like a LinkedList) that ends with `endKey`, without including `endKey.left` and `endKey.right`. I figured I should start by calling the method recursively on either the left or right tree of the root depending on if the startKey is bigger or smaller than the root key, so:

```
if (this.key.compareTo(startKey) < 0) this.right.subset(startKey, endKey);
else if (this.key.compareTo(startKey > 0) this.right.subset(startKey, endKey);
```

That would keep navigating through the tree until it arrives on the node containing the key `startKey`. When I get to that point, I copy `this` to a new tree so I can avoid editing the original tree. This new tree has the node with `startKey` as its root, and then has the same children as the original.

This is where I'm stuck. The problems I know I'll have to deal with is navigating to `endKey`, making sure I stop there and don't include `endKey.left` or `endKey.right`, and return the subset correctly even as the method is "unwinding" from the recursive calls. I'm thinking that if I want to stop at `endKey`, I'll have to somehow keep a reference to its parent node, so that I can set the parent node's left or right child to the key/value pair in order to cut off the rest of `endKey`'s children. However, since I don't really have node objects, and I can't add any methods or constructors, I don't know how I'd be able to maintain a reference to a parent tree. I also don't know how to attempt to pull this off while maintaining `startKey` as the root of the new tree.

In other words, I think I've managed to get a subset of a tree that starts on a lower level and continues to the bottom of the original tree. How can I recursively eliminate the children at the bottom I don't want and return my new subset?

Comment: If your subset can be a view, which means updates on it affect the original tree and vice versa, you can use the original tree as a backing tree in the subset. The method in the subset just check if you are "in range" of the subset, but you perform the methods on the original tree. And you can get a subset of the subset, which means it is recursive. This is exactly how `TreeMap` and its navigable sub views work.

Comment: Like Meini says, you could treat it like a *view* like [List.sublist()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) does, or you could make a *copy* of the subtree. Which implementation is required for the homework. Also please post more code, maybe an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @xtratic I'm not sure I want to treat it as a view, wouldn't doing so mean I'm altering the original tree in the process of returning its subset? I'm pretty sure making a copy of the subtree is what I want.

Comment: And in regards to what @Meini said, I think the subMap() method of TreeMap is exactly how I want, but I don't understand how to to "end" a submap, where I cut it off after it gains a child with a certain key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat it as a view you don't actually cut it out, you just limit the methods  to the range of the subset. When using `iterator()` e.g. the submap just has its own implementation of `Iterator` which start at the lower bound of the submap and just returns `hasNext() == false` when the upper bound is reached. The user won't notice that he is actually iterating over the original tree, because it's completly hidden. I hope this example gives you an idea about it.

```
public interface Tree<X, Y> extends Iterable<Tree<X, Y>> {
    X getKey();
    X getValue();
    Tree<X, Y> floor(X key);
    Tree<X, Y> ceiling(X key);
    Tree<X, Y> subTree(X lo, X hi);
    // ...
}

public class TreeImpl<X, Y> implements Tree<X, Y> {
    final X key;
    Y value;
    TreeImpl<X, Y> left, right;

    public TreeImpl(X key, Y value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Tree<X, Y>> iterator() {
        return new TreeItr();
    }

    // Iterator starting at the most left to the most right;
    private class TreeItr implements Iterator<Tree<X, Y>> {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Tree<X, Y> subTree(X lo, X hi) {
        return new SubTree<>(this, lo, hi);
    }

    private static class SubTree<X, Y> implements Tree<X, Y> {
        final Tree<X, Y> backing;
        final X lo, hi;

        public SubTree(Tree<X, Y> backing, X lo, X hi) {
            this.backing = backing;
            this.lo = lo;
            this.hi = hi;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Tree<X, Y>> iterator() {
            return new SubTreeItr(backing.ceiling(lo), backing.floor(hi))
        }

        // Iterator starting at 'from' and returning 'hasNext() == false' after 'to'
        // has returned
        private class SubTreeItr implements Iterator<Tree<X, Y>> {
            final Tree<X, Y> from, to;

            public SubTreeItr(Tree<X, Y> from, Tree<X, Y> to) {
                this.from = from;
                this.to = to;
            }

            //...
        }

        @Override
        public Tree<X, Y> subTree(X lo, X hi) {
            // Check if lo > this.lo && hi < this.hi
            return new SubTree<>(backing, lo, hi);
        }
    }
}
```